# Issue creating a button variable in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am currently using flutter for an android app and I am using the "Routegenerator.dart" method for navigating . In this project, a certain button gets repeated multiple times and always leads to the same page. I want to create a variable of this button to clean the code a bit and avoid myself useless repetitions. The issue here is that I need to put the variable after the class with the scaffold, and this causes the Navigator.of(context).pushNamed() to give me an error in the (context).
How to solve this issue please?

Comment: can you provide the code that you are using, so I can help you?

Comment: @BehzodFaiziev Thank you for your reply. To answer your question, it's a button I want to repeat, so it will be something like this : class Function {...} var=TextButton(onPressed:(){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Secondscreen')},child:const Text('Choose me'))

Comment: Dou you want button with icon?

Comment: @BehzodFaiziev No, just a button saying choose me, they all lead to a paying screen. So I want to tiptoe the error that appears on the context of the navigator. The issue is not on the decoration or accessories.

Answer (score 0):

you can call TextButtonWidget anywhere in your screen like this:

```
 TextButtonWidget(
         onTap: (){
           Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('anyScreen');
      },),
```

Import this widget

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextButtonWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData _theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: const Text('Choose me')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your effort but I  think there is a misunderstanding concerning the issue, I will update my main post to explain more clearly in the next two hours, please keep updated and hopefully we come to a solution.

Comment: @LawStudies Do yo want to use this custom widget like this : `TextButtonWidget() 
` instead of  `TextButtonWidget(
         onTap: (){
           Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('anyScreen');
      },),`